# Shell "expect" script, how to get returned value after "send" a command

Tags: shell, expect

expect version 5.45

Hi there, I wrote a simple expect script to execute commands on remote linux server with automatic password input. I want to know how to get the returned value from the remote server after command is "send" from local.

Code: no_interact_cmd.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
#usage: no_interact_cmd.sh ip_address username password command
set ip_address [lindex $argv 0]
set username [lindex $argv 1]
set password [lindex $argv 2]
set command [lindex $argv 3]

spawn ssh ${username}@${ip_address}

expect "*password:"
send "${password}\n"

expect "*]#"
send "${command} \n"

expect "*]#"
send "exit\n"

interact
```

For example, I want know hostname of the remote server:`./no_interact_cmd.sh 192.?.?.? root *** 'hostname'`.

hostname of remote_server would be printed, but with many other useless interacted information, how could I get returned value from `send "${command} \n"`? I mean how can `./no_interact_cmd.sh 192.?.?.? root *** 'hostname'` return the value of `${command}` on remote server directly?

Thanks

Comment: take a look at [*sexpect*](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) with which you can write "Expect" scripts with only shell code.

Comment: You have to parse the output by yourself, from either inside or outside of the Expect script.